# HIbernate autoincrement is not working properly

Tags: hibernate

I am saving primary key of table by using auto increment property of hibernate. In my hbm.xml my code is

```
<id name="employeeId" type="integer" column="num_employee_id" >
<generator class="increment"/>
</id>
```

Now, when i am saving any two/three rows in table from front end.So employeeId generated are as 1,2,3 that is in increment order but if i delete third row and then add one more row then employeeId generated is 5 not 4. Or in other case, if i add one more row from backend directly (id generated is 4) and then try to add row from front end, so it will generate id as 4 and gives batchupdateexception. So is there any solution for this.I am using mysql as my database.

Comment: share your database scheme....

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to not use the increment generator, which simply uses a counter in memory, and is thus not aware of the changes done by other applications to the database. This is clearly explained in [the documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.3/manual/en-US/html_single/#mapping-declaration-id-generator):

> increment
>
> generates identifiers of type long, short or int **that are unique only when no other process is inserting data into the same table**. Do not use in a cluster.

(emphasis mine)

Use a strategy that uses the database to generate IDs (an auto_increment column, or a sequence, or even a table, depending on your database capabilities.

Note, though, that you won't find any strategy that guarantees no hole in the IDs, because that is generally impossible to do efficiently, especially when multiple treads/processes access the database concurrently, and may rollback a transaction.

Answer (score 0):

When using hibernate built-in generator 'increment', it's hibernate that generate the identifiers by counting from the maximum primary key value at startup, not safe in multi JVM and using the database AUTO_INCREMENT it's the database that generate a unique identity for new rows.

In mySQL DB, if using AUTO_INCREMENT you should use identity in your mapping to let the database safely generate unique identity.

From hibernate documentation

increment

Generates identifiers of type long, short or int that are unique only when no other process is inserting data into the same table. Do not use in a cluster.

identity

supports identity columns in DB2, MySQL, MS SQL Server, Sybase and HypersonicSQL. The returned identifier is of type long, short or int.